# How to handle canvas unavailability in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've a html page that uses HTML 5 canvas. I've used the below code for creating canvas object.

```
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="200" height="200">
    Canvas Not Supported
</canvas>
```

This works as expected and displays the text **"Canvas Not Supported"** in browsers like IE 8. However, there is a problem with the below javascript associated with the canvas.

```
<script>
    var testCanvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    var testCanvasContext = testCanvas.getContext("2d");
</script>
```

The above code throws an error message **Object doesn't support this property or method** in browsers that don't support canvas. What's the correct approach to handle this in javascript?

Please do not suggest to use libraries like [excanvas](https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas).

Comment: Why not use `try/catch`? Or do you want a polyfill?

Comment: @PeterMader - I don't need a polyfill. Is `try/catch` the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY with the following :

```
<script>
   var testCanvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
   var testCanvasContext = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && testCanvas.getContext("2d");
   if (testCanvasContext) {
      // do stuff
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Am checking other answers also. Please wait.

Comment: ah ohk no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `try/catch` block:

```
function getContext(canvas){
  try {
    // return the context or null
    return (canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')) || null;
  } catch (e) {
    // an error occured; return null
    return null;
  }
}

var testCanvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var testCanvasContext = getContext(testCanvas);
if (testCanvasContext) {
  // supported
} else {
  // not supported
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script you can test for the definition of canvas:

```
if (typeof HTMLCanvasElement !== "undefined") {
  // get canvas and context here
}
else {
  // sorry, canvas not supported in this browser
}
```

An alternative is to use:

```
if ("HTMLCanvasElement" in window) {
  // get canvas and context here
}
else {
  // sorry, canvas not supported in this browser
}
```

Also, when the canvas element is obtained you should check for getContext's return value. This is because can only provide one type of context at a time (f.ex. "2d" vs "webgl"):

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
if (context) { /* all OK */ }
```

Comment: @Beginner no problem :)